# How to convert Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image to byte array for sending it on network?

Tags: maui

On Maui application, I have some button to load Image.

The image is shown on the XAML and on the next click, I need to send the image on network.

I can't find a way to convert the image to byte array to send it.

Comment: Use the data source you originally loaded the image reom

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code to convert the image file in the project to byte array:

```
var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using var stream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.Resources.Images.test.png");
byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
// and then send the bytes
```

The `test.png` is in the `\Resources\Images` and its build action is EmbeddedResource.

And if the image source is from network or local files, you can also use the stream to read and send it.

**Update:**
There is no api can convert the image view to byte[] directly. But there is a solution for the image view which image source is stream.

```
StreamImageSource streamImageSource  = (StreamImageSource) image.Source;
// in the xaml：<Image x:Name="image"/>
var cancellationToken =CancellationToken.None;
var task = streamImageSource.Stream(cancellationToken);
Stream stream = task.Result;
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working

Comment: Can you show the details about not working and the image source in your project? @Yanshof

Comment: just take Image form gallary or any other resource - and trying make his byte[] 

on my app i can't usng GetManifestResourceStream because the image are dynamic from what user select

Comment: If so, you can just convert the image file to the byte[]. Can you show the code about loading image in the button clicked event? The `GetManifestResourceStream` is used for the project embedded resource. @Yanshof

Comment: Did you use the [file picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988155/how-to-convert-microsoft-maui-controls-image-to-byte-array-for-sending-it-on-net/76989598?noredirect=1#comment135723438_76989598)? You can try to get the stream from the file seleted and then use `stream.Rread()` to copy the data to the byte[]. @Yanshof

Comment: yes, I use the file picker - get stream from file select. i alway can keep the byte array of the stream. but i want to do it without keep it from stream if possible. 
i can't belive that microsoft did't give an option to make Image to byte array

Comment: You can check the update part in the answer. @Yanshof

Comment: on line             
StreamImageSource streamImageSource  = (StreamImageSource) image.Source;


Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Comment: You can try to use the `StreamImageSource` as the `image.Source` when you get the filereult by `StreamImageSource source =new(); source.Stream = the stream from the file result`. After this, the error should disappear. @Yanshof

Comment: using StreamImageSource is also not working - i try it already

Comment: So you may still need to keep the byte[] when you get the stream from the file picker. @Yanshof